# Convert query output into table

Tags: html

When do an API call from browser to localhost:5500?requestType=getparam, I obtain an output like this:-

```
{"Param1":"value1","Param2":value2,"Param3":"value3"}
```

How can I write a simple html page to do the same query but have the output in the form of a table with 3 rows & 2 columns?

Param1 value1

Param2 value2

Param3 value3

Thank you!

EDit:
I have a server running in an RaspberryPi on my local network. When I type this URL localhost:5500?requestType=getparam into browser, my browser displays this {"Param1":"value1","Param2":value2,"Param3":"value3"}
Is there a way for me to write a simple html page to get the same info and then display it in a table form?
Thanks for your patience. Real newbie here

Comment: Plain HTML pages don't do queries.  Please more clearly explain what you are doing.

Comment: I have a server running in an RaspberryPi on my local network. When I type this URL localhost:5500?requestType=getparam into browser, my browser displays this {"Param1":"value1","Param2":value2,"Param3":"value3"}

Comment: that looks like json... maybe you can decode it with php and loop it out into a html table.

Comment: What application do you have running on port 5500 that is producing that result?